# Ajax request with PHP in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to connect with my database and get some data with Ajax and PHP. I have created a Web App in ASP.NET, i am using Azure Data Studio for database. I do not know how to execute all of this. How can i run the php script, how can i get data from database without reloading the page on changing value in a dropdown. 
My connection string is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {"ConnectionString":"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName; Trusted_Connection=True;"}
```

My HTML Code is:

```
<form action=""> 
    <select name="customers" onchange="showValue(this.value)">
         <option value="">Select a customer:</option>
         <option value="1">One</option>
         <option value="2">Two</option>
         <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txt">Here is info..</div>
```

My Ajax request, function in JS:

```
function showValue(str) {
    var xhttp;  
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "getValue.php?q="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

And finally my PHP script:

```
<?php
$servername = "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "DatabaseName";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
  exit('Could not connect');
}

$sql = "SELECT Id, Name, Number
FROM Table1 WHERE Id = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['q']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $number);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
echo "<th>Number</th>";
echo "<td>" . $number . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Connect to MSSQL server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15